# .NET Remoting: monitoring events on server

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

First of all, sorry for my english. It's not my native language.

Here is the problem: I'm writing client-server application based on .net remoting. The application is some kind of calculator.

Client application has some field(number A and number B, and label for result) and some possible actions, represented by the buttons: Add, Substract, Multiply, Divide, etc..

Server application is a console application, that should habe following functions:

- make this calculations
- detect, what actions are done by the specific client.

Eg of output:

```
Server started
Client A(IP: 192.168.0.133) connected<br>
Client A Add 18 to 12<br>
Client A disconnected
```

The main problem is - how to get actions on server and how can i detect, what clients do.
Thx for help.

Comment: Your English is fine!  Could you provide a little more info though on what you need to monitor on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 *common* ways for tracing with .NET Remoting:

- Turn on trace in app.config
- Use [Remoting Analyzator Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/remotingprobe.aspx), an open-source project from Codeproject.com.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be ideal, but you can create a custom sink that hooks into the remoting channel which logs all remoting traffic. You can learn how to create a custom sink from Ingo Rammer's [Advanced .NET Remoting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594177) book.

I've used his book to create custom sinks in the past.

Answer (score 0):

We modified Mono TCP remoting channel to do this. It takes like 30 minutes and you can add information about the method call being invoked, time to execute and so on. It turns out to be a extremely good tool to measure performance on real servers. You can parse the output and learn which methods are taking more time, sending or receiving more data and so on. Really helpful.